# Redirect non www to www sub pages also

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

in .htaccess Am using :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

It works fine for main domain i.e. redirects example.com to https://www.example.com

but not works on sub pages like

site.com/blog not redirects to https://www.example.com/blog

also like to add tailing slash '/' after url

https://www.example.com/blog/

how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have htaccess rule like this. Make sure you keep these rules at the top of your htaccess file. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [NE,R=301,L]
```